# How to get Karma to start Chrome with a specific language?

Tags: google-chrome, locale, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, test-runner

I am using [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/) as a test runner to execute my Jasmine unit tests. Is there a possibility to tell Karma that it should always start a Chrome instance with an English locale?

My current Karma configuration is this:

```
// available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
browsers: [process.env.TRAVIS ? 'Chrome_travis_ci' : 'Chrome'],
customLaunchers: {
  Chrome_travis_ci: {
    base: 'Chrome',
    flags: ['--no-sandbox']
  }
}
```